# Assign values to variables by reading from a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a sample file which looks like below.

```
cat sample
'c2.url0' :  'k8s-abc1.amazonaws.com : 1000'
'c2.url1' :  'k8s-abc2.amazonaws.com : 1001'
'c2.url2' :  'k8s-xyz1.amazonaws.com : 1003'
```

From this I want to get urls and assign it to a variable with same name as key.(i.e)if I do echo $c2.url0 then output should be "k8s-abc1.amazonaws.com : 1000".Similarly for other keys.

```
echo $c2.url0 should print --> "k8s-abc1.amazonaws.com : 1000"
echo $c2.url1 should print --> "k8s-abc2.amazonaws.com : 1001"
echo $c2.url2 should print --> "k8s-xyz1.amazonaws.com : 1003"
```

I have tried like

```
  lenc2=$(cat sample | grep c2|wc -l)

#Get LBs of cluster_2 ###
  j=0
    while [ $j -lt $lenc2 ]
  do
        LB=$(cat sample | grep c2.url$j| awk -F: '{print  $(NF-1),":",$(NF)}'|sed "s/'/\"/g")
        c2.url"$j"=$LB
        j=$(( j + 1 ))
  done
```

But while assigning value to variable i am facing issue.

```
 c2.url0=: command not found
 c2.url1=: command not found
 c2.url2=: command not found
```

Please help !!

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? Do you understand why the problem is happening? Have you considered using an associative array instead?

Comment: The `c2.url"$j"=$LB` does not work. In a variable assignment, you can't have a parameter expansion to the left of the equal sign. Therefore, bash interprets this as a command. You could use `eval`, or a _nameref_, or an associative array. In your case, an associative array would perhaps most suitable, but IMO the main problem in your program is that you create 4 child processes for each line of the file _sample_.  You could instead simply loop over the lines of your file and from each line assign your array (no child process needed).

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't use a dot to separate keys.

First, you need to declare an associative array.

```sh
declare -A c2
```

Then, you can use syntax similar to the array bash syntax:

```sh
while read line ; do
    key=$(cut -f2 -d\' <<< "$line")
    url=$(cut -f4 -d\' <<< "$line")
    
    c2[${key#c2.}]=$url  # Remove "c2." from the left.
done < sample

echo "${c2[url0]}"
```

Comment: or just `while IFS="'" read -r _ key _ url _; do` and avoid the `cut`s.